# Black screen with blinking cursor in top left corner

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

My system: Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15.0-58-generic, NVIDIA RTX 2060 SUPER 8GB, 64GB Memory, 02 Intel Xeon E5 v3/core i7 physical processors, each with 12 cores, HD SSD).

After updating the system `sudo apt` (`update`, `upgrade`, `autoremove` and `clean`) I worked normally on my PC, during the whole afternoon. The day after, `lightdm` does not start, there is a black screen with the cursor blinking on the top left corner.
I've done everything, including installing the nvidia driver version 525.85.05 and it still didn't work.

I even changed the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and it didn't work.
I changed `/etc/default/grub` adding the parameters "`i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2`", and it didn't work either...

I changed the monitor cables to "Display Port, HDMI and DVI" and that didn't work either...
Note: I downloaded the "`Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64.iso`" image from the Ubuntu website, mounted the OS on a bootable USB stick and was able to run Ubuntu perfectly with a perfect graphical environment.
However starting the initialization/boot by the PC itself does not open the `Lightdm` desktop...

Comment: Try removing that NVIDIA driver and installing the one from the repos.  `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`.  The drivers from the repos have been tested for the installation.  Plus, if you tried installing the `-open` version of the NVIDIA drivers they only works on specific cards and yours is not one of them.  The supported cards for the `-open` drivers are listed at https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/196728/en-us/  NOTE:  The NVIDIA drivers from the repo carry over into new Kernel updates and upgrades.

Comment: Thanks friend, I did the procedure you indicated, I removed the NVIDIA downloaded from the **nvidia.com** website and installed the one from the Ubuntu repository, but it didn't work. So I installed **GDM3** - commad: `apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` set it as default, but it didn't work either... I'm desperate. Kindly help me...

Comment: GDM3 is installed just by `sudo apt install gdm3` then it is chosen during the setup.  Anyway, I would recommend booting to the previous kernel.  Sometimes during kernel upgrades drivers don't transfer properly over.

Comment: I also did the procedures indicated by the friend, however, it did not work